# Missing SLF4J logger on spark workers

Tags: apache-spark, jar, pyspark, slf4j

I am trying to run a job via `spark-submit`.

The error that results from this job is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

Not sure if it matters, but I am trying to run this job within a Docker container on Mesos. Spark is 1.61, Mesos is 0.27.1, Python is 3.5, and Docker is 1.11.2. I am running in client mode.

Here is the gist of my `spark-submit` statement:

```
export SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=true
./spark-submit \
    --master mesos://mesos-blahblahblah:port \
    --conf spark.mesos.executor.docker.image=docker-registry:spark-docker-image \
    --conf spark.mesos.executor.home=/usr/local/spark \
    --conf spark.executorEnv.MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.dylib \
    --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
    --jars ~/spark/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar \
    test.py
```

The gist of `test.py` is that it loads data from parquet, sorts it by a particular column, and then writes it back to parquet.

I added the `--jars` line when I kept getting that error (the error is not appearing in my driver - I navigate through the Mesos Framework to look at the stderr from each Mesos task to find it)

I also tried adding `--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=http:some.ip:port/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar`,

because I noticed when I ran the `spark-submit` from above it would output

`INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:~/spark/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar at http://some.ip:port/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar with timestamp 1472138630497`

But the error is unchanged. Any ideas?

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832804/spark-1-5-2-and-slf4j-staticloggerbinder), which makes me think it is a bug. But the person hasn't posted any solution.

Comment: Usually when I submit applications on yarn I use a combination of `--jars` and `--files` config parameters and that seems to work.

Comment: Did you ever solve this error?

Comment: @FGreg no I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem and was also trying to run Mesos/Spark/Python on Docker.

The thing that finally fixed it for me was to add the `hadoop classpath` output to the Classpath of the Spark executors using the `spark.executor.extraClassPath` configuration option.

The full command I ran to get it to work was:

```
MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so \
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/pyspark --conf spark.master=mesos://mesos-master:5050 --driver-class-path $(${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop classpath) --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=$(${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop classpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the Exception is correct - org/slf4j/Logger is not present in the mentioned "slf4j-simple-1.7.21" jar:

```
└── org
└── slf4j
    └── impl
        ├── SimpleLogger$1.class
        ├── SimpleLogger.class
        ├── SimpleLoggerFactory.class
        ├── StaticLoggerBinder.class
        ├── StaticMDCBinder.class
        └── StaticMarkerBinder.class
```

Include the proper jar (try slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar)

(Hint - You can simply check the content of the jar file by unzipping it)